# Find out which identifiers are unresolved in a tsx script

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, tsx, typescript-compiler-api

I am currently developing a custom builder for a web app.
Now it is required that the imports are detected automatically, so I need to know which identifiers in tsx source code are unresolved, so that my script can import the right modules.

The solution I am currently working on traverses the AST of the scripts, storing declared identifiers in the currently processed scope, and then return the unresolved identifiers. But this requires much work for different handling of different types of AST-elements.

So since the tsc and also the ts background server, have such capability built in. I am wondering whether anyone could tell me how they do it or at least where they do it, since I couldn't find a specific piece of code for that.

Thanks

Luca

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found kind of a solution. Using the AST was not that easy and I got some hard to work around cases, where  it was difficult to decide which identifier are valid for the current scope.

So I am using the typescript compiler to get the error messages. Each error messages is filtered and the error message is parsed to get the identifier Name. This is not pretty but it works. I also saw that after the diagnostics SourfeFileObjects with occured errors, also include the exported Identifiers. I need thoose too, but I am getting them via the AST directly.

```
let compilerHost = {
    getSourceFile: (fname: string) => {...},
    writeFile: (name: string, text: string) => {...},
    getDefaultLibFileName: () => Path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts"),
    useCaseSensitiveFileNames: () => false,
    getCanonicalFileName: (fileName : string) => fileName,
    getCurrentDirectory: () => "",
    getNewLine: () => "\n",
    fileExists: (fname: string): boolean => {...},
    readFile: (fileName: string) => {...},
    directoryExists: (dname: string) => {...},
    getDirectories: () => []
};

let unresolved = []
let sourceFile = TS.createSourceFile(filepath, tsCode, TS.ScriptTarget.ES5, true, TS.ScriptKind.TSX);
let program = TS.createProgram([filepath], tsCompilerOptions, compilerHost);
let semanticDiagnostic = program.getSemanticDiagnostics();
if(semanticDiagnostic.length){
    unresolved = <string[]>semanticDiagnostic
        // Filter for Unresolved names
        .filter(m=>m.code == 2304 && m.file == this.sourceFile)
        .map(m=>{
            let matches = (m.messageText as string).match(/^Cannot find name '([A-Z]\w+)'.$/)
            if(matches){
                return matches[1];
            }
        })
        .filter(sym=>typeof(sym)=="string");
}
```